# iOS tabbar item ignoring title position

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I would like to add some space below the tabbar item titles. So I have tried first using storyboards:
[image: uikit]

The changes are reflected in the storyboard but not at running time in the simulator.

I have tried also programmatically:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment.vertical = -2
```

or:

```
tabBar.items!.forEach {
     $0.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -2) 
}
```

but also it does not work.

Do you know if I could have some missconfiguration?

Comment: Making the adjustment you have shown in the storyboard, for example, works fine on my machine (in the running app on the simulator). Just try this in a fresh app consisting of nothing but a tab bar controller and its children, and you will see. — So clearly you must have _other_ code that comes along and changes things. But you have not shown it to us.

Comment: No, there is no code making changes over this tabbar

Comment: You can say that, but from what you’ve said the issue cannot be reproduced. That’s just a fact. I did what you showed in the storyboard editor and ran the project in the Simulator and the title was indeed two points higher.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn´t realize that I had some appearance code overriding my code. You was right:

```
let appearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
```